# BroadcastReceiver and PostDelay

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

In my activity I have a private `BroadcastReceiver`, when triggered, should update the UI after some ms. In my Activity I have:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("BroadCastReciever: ", "UpdateCaseList");
    update.RefreshCaseList();
  }
};
```

This `BroadcastReceiver` is beeing triggered from a `Service`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 0);
    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
            sendUpdateToUiThread();         
        }
    };

    private void sendUpdateToUiThread() {
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

I guess that the `onStart` method is being called when I Register BroadcastReceiver in my `OnResume()` method. I also unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` in `onPause`.

My intention is that this should sent a notification to the `Activity`, every 10 seconds. Once I start the application, my service will notify the Activity every 10 seconds, as planned. The problem is when I leave the Activity and return back, it doesn't post a notification to the `activity` every 10 seconds, but just at a random time. I can see in `LogCat` that this randomness spamming occurs every 4, 6, 3, 8, 6 seconds and so on. Why on earth this behaviour?

Comment: Is there a reason for using the `onStart` callback that has been deprecated from API level 5? Make sure you're calling `startService()` only if the `Service` isn't running.

Comment: Could you suggest a other solution if the onStart method is deprecated? Thanks.

Comment: You have the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29 method.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`postDelayed` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))
the Runnable is called **after** millisecods elapsed and

> Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay to execution.

So some randomness is by design. So I would expect the Runnable called after **more** than 10000 ms in your case.